# Install Solr 6.5.1 in Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS into a custom directory

Tags: ubuntu, solr

I am trying to install `Solr 6.5.1` in `Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS`. I have used the following commands to install `Java` and `Solr`

```
Installing Java

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer

Installing Solr
cd /vm/solr
sudo wget http://mirror.fibergrid.in/apache/lucene/solr/6.6.0/solr-6.6.0.tgz
sudo tar xzf solr-6.6.0.tgz solr-6.6.0/bin/install_solr_service.sh --strip-components=2
sudo bash ./install_solr_service.sh solr-6.6.0.tgz
```

Even though I tried to install Solr in `/vm/solr` i found that Solr was installed in `/opt` which I believe is the default installation directory.

Is there a way to install Solr in the directory we specify or change the home directory after installation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just by cd-ing to a directory, where you run the install script WILL NOT make it install into that dir.

The installation script accepts an option for that:

> -i     Directory to extract the Solr installation archive; defaults to /opt
>          The specified path must exist prior to using this script

So try by running:

```
sudo bash ./install_solr_service.sh solr-6.6.0.tgz -i /vm/solr
```